# How to select all child elements of specified control using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a `<table id="myTable">` with a number of child elements:

```
<tr><td>
   <span class="mySpan" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
   <span class="mySpan" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
   <span class="mySpan" />
</td></tr>
```

How to select all this spans using jQuery?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that you COULD do any of the following:

```
$("#myTable").find(".mySpan");
$("#myTable .mySpan");
$("#myTable tr td .mySpan");
$("#myTable").find("tr").find("td").children(".mySpan");
$(".mySpan");
$("#myTable > tr > td > .mySpan");
$(".mySpan ,#myTable");
```

Comment: I would note that the first is likely the best due to the right to left selector in sizzle and those with combined selectors likely worst (second to last and the third one)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#myTable span.mySpan')
```

Answer (score 1):

"Safest" version:

```
var spans = $("#myTable tr td span.mySpan");
```

Shortest version:

```
var spans = $("#myTable .mySpan");
```

Comment: shortest would be $(".mySpan"), but adding the #myTable should be faster as it starts at the table and not the document root.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss but you can know if there are other spans in the document that match .mySpan :)

Comment: Yes, hence my explaination (faster, more precise with #myTable :)  I do agree your answers are NOT "wrong" either :)